# Looking for heroku db backup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

By accident I run a script which was supposed to go through all rows and change a field in each row. But it messed up and set this field nil for each of the rows. I am looking for a way to get the previous version of my prod. db, does heroku keep automatically db dumps?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have to have manually backup your DB prior to a mess up.  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups

Answer (score 1):

At first you need to install `PgAdmin` http://www.pgadmin.org/  then you need to connect your heroku database with the PgAdmin for that.

1. login to [heroku dev center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/)
2. Go to dash board --> databases-->select app database --> connection settings
3. Copy the details like database name, password,host
4. Click on add a new connection in `PgAdmin`
5. Paste above settings.
   Now you have live db connection like `Heroku,` then backup from `PgAdmin` there.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku [provides a backup service](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups) called PGBackups, however you should have either configured it to run your backups periodically, or run a manual backup **before** performing the operation.

If you didn't configure any backup, then your only chance is to contact Heroku support and check if they can recover a previous backup for you.

Needless to say that you should always be prepared for such circumstance and you should really have configured a backup of your data.